# Filtering categories

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, filtering

In my app I have a list of providers, and each provider has categories. My models look as follows:

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :provider
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :providers, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end

class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

In a view, I have 2 `ul` lists. The first one is a list with providers, and the second one - a list of categories. It looks like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified nav-carousel upper-thumbs">
    <% Provider.order(created_at: :asc).take(6).each_with_index do |provider, index| %>
      <li id="<%= provider.name %>_<%= index + 1 %>" class="btn-up"><a data-href="#"><%= provider.name %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<ul id="parent" class="nav nav-justified nav-carousel left-thumbs">
    <% Category.order(created_at: :asc).take(7).each_with_index do |category, index| %>
      <li id="aside_<%= index + 1 %>" class="btn-aside"><i class="category_image" style="background: url(<%= category.cat_image %>) no-repeat;"></i><a data-href="#"><%= category.name %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

When I had no rails implementation, when I clicked on the provider (it was hardcoded, as well, as the categories), I could see, the categories were filtered. It was made by js:

```
var $btns = $('.btn-up').click(function () {
      if(this.id == 'a') {
          $('#parent > li#aside_1').fadeIn(450);
          $('#parent > li').not($('#parent > li#aside_1')).hide();
      } else {
          var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
          $('#parent > li').not($el).hide();
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  })
```

So,the question is how to make the filter work, so when I click on a provider, it will show me only the categories, which belongs to that provider? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is best way to do this kind of things.

ex.

```
var $btns = $('.btn-aside').click(function () {
var provider_id = 'get selected provider via JS'   
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/some_url_of_controller_method",
  data: {
    provider: provider_id
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('.btn-up').empty()
    $.each(data, function(){
    $('.btn-up').append('<option value="'+ this.value +'">'+ this.name  +'</option>')
)
  },
  error: function(data) {
    return false;
  }
    });
})
```

**SomeContoller.rb**

```
def some_method
 @provider = Provider.find_by_id(params[:provider])
 @categories = @provider.categories
 respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @categories}
 end
end
```

Comment: I've added a link into a view: `<%= link_to provider.name, fetch_providers_path(provider: provider.id), remote: true %>`, so that now I can pass propper params to controller, and I pass in ajax call on `done()` propper values from `json`, but nothing seems to change, categories are still the same, they don't `empty()`

Comment: Made it a more rails way, by creating a file `some_method.js.erb`, and in that file I did all the manipulations I needed. Thaks for your answer, it pushed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So here is one approach you can take to achieve this.

You can send AJAX request every time you click on a Provider to fetch its associated categories and append it to your HTML using JQuery.

The code is quite elaborate to paste here, hence I suggest you to go through this video to understand how it works and implement it in a way that works for you.

Ryan Bates explains this concept very well in the below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk