# Base collection_select on selected value from other

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I googled for a while and tried different things, but none seem to be working or they all seem to be focused on using 2 tables. The question i have is:
How do i populate 1 dropdown based on the selected value of another dropdown.

I have a table: Measurements, where i first want to select a measurement_type and then in the second table one of the measurements belonging to that type.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:measurement_id, Measurement.all, :id, :measurement, prompt: true) %>
```

and one for measurement_type

Comment: i think you choosing the wrong keywords, try search with 'Dynamic select with Rails'

Comment: do you need an api call after the first select is made?, please add some code.

Comment: I have no idea. I do not have any code for this issue yet. well, i have 1 collection_select, but that is just a normal one.

Comment: also, why the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is similar to you and may helpful to you.

[Filtering categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674555/filtering-categories/41675121#41675121)

Comment: I did see that question. However, like most others that i found, it uses 2 tables so i havn't really looked into that. But i will see if i can use it anyway.

Comment: Not necessary to use two table, main concept is use Ajax to get data on the fly. and you can write any kind of logic that you want in your controller def.

Comment: Ah, thanks, i will look into it. As i am new to programming(well, only used .net before) i never did anything with Ajax.

Comment: I assume the ajax code has to go in the coffee file belonging to the controller? And can i just use the collection_select dropdowns i have now?

Comment: yes, you can. and please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327282/rails-ajax-getting-a-dropdown-selection-to-populate-a-table

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had no succes yet, so decided to go with a bit different method first: '  <%= f.collection_select(:measurement_id, Measurement.all.sort_by { |m|m.measurementtype}, :id, :type_and_measurement, {:prompt => 'Type | Maatregel'}, class: 'ui search dropdown' ) %>
'where type_and _measurement is a combination of both, seperated by a |